# UIPageControl bullets improve the accessibility touch voice over

Tags: ios, uipagecontrol

I need to improve the transition of EAIntroView screens from my application when voice over is enabled. For this I thought about increasing the touch area using the transform:

```
    _pageControl.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.0, 35.0);
```

But control items are stretched: [Stretched control item](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XKrFz.png). How can I improve the touch area of the page control, which usually looks like this: [normal page control](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OEins.png).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to solve my problem using another method:

```
    _pageControl.frame = CGRectMake(0.f, 0.f, 100, 100);
```

Thus, I increased the touch area of the control items allowing better accessibility.